# Does SSL certificate work on reactjs re-render?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, web, server, public-key-encryption

In react web application we update UI based on state.

How SSL encryption work when we change the UI.

Codes encrypted by SSL when it comes from the server.

But how it works when we are directly manipulate the UI using reactjs.

Comment: SSL/TLS works on network traffic. For client-side manipulation there's no network traffic so there's nothing to encrypt.